# UMAP plot string labels next to dots

Tags: python, plot, tsne

```
mapper = umap.UMAP(n_neighbors=5, metric='hamming').fit(data.drop('pid',axis=1))
umap.plot.points(mapper,labels=np.array(clusters['leaves_color_list']))
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

Instead of/In addition to colored dots, I'd like to plot the 'pid' labels (string). I need to see which dots correspond to which data.